# Reactive document title in template vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I tried to use [vue-headful](https://github.com/troxler/vue-headful) and [vue-meta](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta), but none of them allowed me to realize what I wanted.
I would like the component title to be set to the title of the page (document) with a specific pattern: "pageTitle | siteTitle".

vue-meta: copes well with this task.
vue-headful: just set the title I understood how. How to set a common template for all components?

Next requirement: I would like in the application component (App.vue) to display the current component title in the template, with reactivity support.
vue-meta: it was easy to extract the title of the first component in the route list, but there was no reactivity.
vue-headful: how to get access to the title (not modify, just read in App.vue title of other/current component), I did not understand. How to get reactivity especially.